# Python Returning Variable From Nested If Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, arraylist, return

I am a beginner and wondering how I can to manage the program to go to a function depending on whether the year is a leap year. Here is the code I have. Maybe I can direct this function to return a variable that says the year is either a regular year or a leap year and depending on that resulting variable I can choose which function it would go to next? I'm not sure how to do that or if there is a better way to do this.

```
def get_year():
    print("Enter a year:")
    year = int(input())
    return year


def leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                print("This is a leap year")
            else:
                print("This is not a leap year")
        else:
            print("This is a leap year")
    else:
        print("This is not a leap year")


def main():
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
              "November", "December"]
    days_leap = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30]
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30]
    year = get_year()
    leap_year(year)


main()
```

Comment: instead of `print()` use `return True` and `return False` and `result = leap_year(year)`. And when you will have result then you can print text or use it in other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                print("This is a leap year")
                return True
            else:
                print("This is not a leap year")
                return False
        else:
            print("This is a leap year")
            return True
    else:
        print("This is not a leap year")
        return False
```

That way, you can later say:

```
if leap_year(year):
    doAThing()
else:
    doADifferentThing()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `print()` use `return True` and `return False` and `result = leap_year(year)`. And when you will have `result` then you can print text or use `result` in other function.

```
def get_year():
    print("Enter a year:")
    year = int(input())
    return year

def leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
              "November", "December"]
    days_leap = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30]
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30]
    year = get_year()
    
    result = leap_year(year)
    
    if result:
        print("This is a leap year")
    else:
        print("This is not a leap year")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
year=int(input("Enter a year:"))

if(year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0):
    print("This is a leap year")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year")
```

The combination of conditions directly gives a boolean that you can check! The simple "if condition: do" is the same than "if condition==True: do".

Comment: Then how do you explain 2004%4=0, 2004%100=4, 2004%400=4? It's only one example, there are many others. Sorry but I highly disagree with your comment and associated answer. Please see e.g. the first paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_leap_year . Even if the "mathematical nonsense" you describe was correct (which is not), it would only be a redundancy, no nonsense.

Comment: Mea Culpa, Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"...how to do that or if there is a better way to do this."*

No nesting is necessary at all here, re-use the complex, calendar revisions, astronomic leap-seconds and other irregularities aware `datetime` module:

```
def leap_year( aYear ): #### TEST datetime.date( 1700, 2, 29 )
    try:
         datetime.date( aYear, 2, 29 )
         return True
    except:
         return False
```

---

```
leap_year( 1492 ) # Columbus discovered a shorter way to ... India & thus 've met indians
True
```

---

### PERFORMANCE :

No more than this few python SYM-OPs needed :

```
>>> dis.dis( leap_year )
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            27 (to 30)

  3           3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (datetime)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (date)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (aYear)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (29)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             21 POP_TOP             
 
  4          22 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (True)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
             26 POP_BLOCK           
             27 JUMP_FORWARD             8 (to 38)

  5     >>   30 POP_TOP             
             31 POP_TOP             
             32 POP_TOP             

  6          33 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (False)
             36 RETURN_VALUE        
             37 END_FINALLY         
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

> Welcome to the *re-inventing* of the shortest path to the ***New World !*** <sub>*( ... the Columbus way )*</sub>
>  :o)

---

### Compared to the original :

```
>>> dis.dis( leap_year )
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (year)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              6 BINARY_MODULO       
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       81

  3          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (year)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (100)
             22 BINARY_MODULO       
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             29 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       69

  4          32 LOAD_FAST                0 (year)
             35 LOAD_CONST               4 (400)
             38 BINARY_MODULO       
             39 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             42 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             45 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       57

  5          48 LOAD_CONST               5 ('This is a leap year')
             51 PRINT_ITEM          
             52 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  6          53 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             56 RETURN_VALUE        

  8     >>   57 LOAD_CONST               6 ('This is not a leap year')
             60 PRINT_ITEM          
             61 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  9          62 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             65 RETURN_VALUE        
             66 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           90

 11     >>   69 LOAD_CONST               5 ('This is a leap year')
             72 PRINT_ITEM          
             73 PRINT_NEWLINE       

 12          74 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             77 RETURN_VALUE        
             78 JUMP_FORWARD             9 (to 90)

 14     >>   81 LOAD_CONST               6 ('This is not a leap year')
             84 PRINT_ITEM          
             85 PRINT_NEWLINE       

 15          86 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             89 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   90 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             93 RETURN_VALUE
```